# 'Permission denied' when checking if a file exists in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, filesystems

I have a VBS script that is to copy a file from an old user profile to a new one, if it exists, but I'm being shown a 'Permission denied' error when using the `objFSO.FileExists()` method.

To check the file, I map a drive (working fine, and `objFSO.FolderExists()` checks are working ok) and pass my username/password (I am an admin, so have access to all profiles, but this is even failing on my own profile).

Full scrip is in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yBsA1R9x) (Line 106 for the code in question), I'd be greatful for some tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping method with user/password often gives trouble because the script runs in another security context than the user you use to do the mapping. You do need the mapping though to get permission to read the file so the safest to do is use the mapping but afterward use the UNC to access the file, not the path with the driveletter.

So instead of

```
old_nicknames_file_path = "J:\" & user_name & "\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook"
```

use

```
old_nicknames_file_path = "\\server\d$\__OLD-PROFILES\" & user_name & "\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook"
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, will give it a try. I also noticed that I missed a trailing slash on line 116, which seems to have now sorted the script (even though it was reporting the error on 106).